# Oracle SQL: Select rows from table A with fallback to joined table A and B. (union, group by,...)

Tags: oracle, join, union

The requirement may seem a bit odd, but bear with me: Lets say I have a list of my `employees` like this:

```
pid    name
-------------------------
  1    Smith-Gordon
  2    Hansen
  3    Simpson
```

And a table of previous names (if e.g. Mrs Smith-Gordon and Mr Hansen had one or more different names before they were married, respectively), `employeehist`:

```
pid    oldname
-------------------------
  1    Smith
  2    Taylor
  2    Baker
```

What I want now is to be able to search for names and get results from both tables like this:

a) Search for "Simpson%" -> Get a result like "3, Simpson"

b) Search for "Hansen%" -> Get a result like "2, Hansen"

c) Search for "Taylor%" -> Get a result like "2, Hansen, matched on previous Taylor"

d) Search for "Smith%" -> Get a result like "1, Smith-Gordon"

In other words, I want the current record, plus the old name *if that was where the pertinent match occurred.*

**What I tried so far:**

1) Naively join the history to the current employees: The searches b), c) and d) will always contain something in the `oldname` column, so I can't tell where the match occurred. I also get duplicate hits for Mr Hansen.

2) I tried to `UNION` a first select on `employees` (containing a dummy `NULL AS oldname`) with a second select joining `employeehist` with `employees` which will return me a nice hit for search b) without an `oldname` and one with an `oldname` for c), but now I predictably get duplicates in d).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by  I can't tell where the match occurred.  Are you wanting to see the old record that caused the matched or just a list of employee and PID's that relate?  I guess I need to see some expected results given your sample data.

Comment: Baker is pid=3 or Hansen marry twice?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I'm assuming two name changes for Hansen here, in order to cover that corner case that I wouldn't want duplicates in the results.

Comment: @xQbert - I have a number of expected results in my question. What I want is to be able to differentiate between examples b) and c). If I just join the two tables then b) would give something like ``2, Hansen, previously Taylor`` as well as ``2, Hansen, previously Baker``, while c) would give me ``2, Hansen, previously Taylor``. The thing is, for b) in this case I don't want two results, and I don't want to know about the previous names because that's not where the match was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better solution than my previous one. My problem was that I couldn't `GROUP BY` pid and "squash" differing `oldname` rows. I'm quite sure I remember that this was possible in MySQL, but Oracle always ever gave me "979: not a GROUP BY expression". Strict but fair.

The solution is apparently to provide Oracle with a strategy how to deal with those rows:

```
SELECT pid, name,
  MIN(oldname) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY oldname NULLS FIRST) as oldname
/*(3) outer select combines current and old hits, and "squashes" duplicates, preferring current hits where available*/
FROM (
  SELECT e.pid, e.name, null AS oldname /*(1) hits in current names*/
  FROM employees e
  WHERE e.name LIKE :search_key
  UNION ALL
  SELECT e.pid, e.name, eh.oldname /* (2) hits in old names*/
  FROM employeehist eh
  JOIN employees e ON e.pid = eh.pid
  WHERE eh.oldname LIKE :search_key
) combined
GROUP BY pid, name;
```

The idea is simple: Run a query (1) that gives all matches in current names (plus a dummy "oldname" column with NULLs), then a query (2) that gives all matches in old names (complete with their joined current names to display). Then simply combine those, and remove the duplicates by `pid` (and `name`, because Oracle, but that's identical by definition) giving preference to rows where `oldname` is `NULL`.

This would return e.g. for search key "Smith%"

```
pid  | name         | oldname
  1  | Smith-Gordon | NULL
```

which is exactly what I want. If there's a pid with a current and an old match, I don't care about the old one. Or for "Taylor%":

```
pid  | name         | oldname
  2  | Hansen       | Taylor
```

This query also appears to be roughly 10 times faster than my other solution - I guess because it avoids subqueries that depend on the current pid.

So the only odd thing is that I need to use `MIN(oldname)` instead of some form of identity. I get that Oracle needs an aggregate function here, but the whole point of the KEEP ... FIRST exercise is to only have one row anyway, no?

But it works, and it's fast, so I won't complain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query with a parameter:

```
SELECT e.pid,
       CASE
           WHEN e.name LIKE :search_key THEN e.name
           WHEN eh.oldname LIKE :search_key THEN e.name || ' matched on previous ' || eh.oldname
       END
  FROM employees e
  LEFT JOIN employeehist eh on (e.pid = eh.pid)
 WHERE e.name LIKE :seach_key OR eh.oldname LIKE :search_key
```

Comment: Yeah, I think CASE is the way to go here, although I dislike that I have to do the matching multiple times (my business case is more complex than the example discussed here) and that I don't get the old name in a separate column. (The latter obviously can be done by adjusting your fine solution.)

Comment: Hm. But wouldn't this also return multiple hits for "hansen"? Or could I use ``GROUP BY`` to get rid of those? I've had trouble with those before in this case because Oracle won't let me "squash" rows with different conent (except aggregates) in the non-grouped columns. Here, I've been getting 979: Not a GROUP BY expression many times. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with this solution:

```
SELECT * FROM ( /* (3) outer filter query */
  SELECT e.pid, e.name,  /* (1) query combining current and matching old names */
  CASE
    WHEN e.name LIKE :search_key THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END AS primary_match,
  (
    SELECT oldname  /* (2) subquery that gives me one or no matching old name */
    FROM employeehist eh
    WHERE eh.pid = e.pid
    AND eh.oldname LIKE :search_key
    AND ROWNUM=1
  )
  FROM employees e
) combined
WHERE combined.primary_match = 'Y' OR combined.oldname IS NOT NULL;
```

There's one primary select (1) that gets me all current ids and names, and adds a CASE column whether the name matched. Additionally, it runs a subquery (2) that gets me one matching old name (also if there are several, or none if none). With that on hand I can use an outer select (2) that will filter away rows with no matches.

This would return e.g. for search key "Smith%"

```
pid  | name         | primary_match  | oldname
  1  | Smith-Gordon | Y              | Smith
```

or for "Taylor%"

```
pid  | name         | primary_match  | oldname
  2  | Hansen       | N              | Taylor
```

I'm not sure how elegant it is, but it works as I want:

- I get one result per matching current `pid`, no matter how many old names that `pid` has, matching or not. No duplicates.
- I can distinguish between results that matched on the current name and those that ("only" or "also") matched on old names.
- I don't need to define my matching condition twice because it gets rolled into that CASE column and I can filter on that.

There's obviously room for improvement: The subquery (2) could be made to return an aggregate of all matching old names (or the newest or oldest, I have a column for that).

But this works for me.